# Is it possible to set accessTokenValiditySeconds dynamically from AuthenticationProvider implemented class?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

I want to dynamically set accessTokenValiditySeconds value from DB. Is it possible to fetch value in AuthenticationProvider and set it? or is there any other way we can do it?
Currently i'm using yaml file and fetching value from it. Now i want to fetch the token validity seconds value from DB. How can i do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible!

```
@Component
public class TokenProvider implements InitializingBean {
   private long tokenValidityInMilliseconds;

   private final ConfigRepository configRepository;

    public TokenProvider(ConfigRepository mealRepository) {
        this.configRepository = configRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
       Config myConfig = configRepository.findAll().get(0);
       this.tokenValidityInMilliseconds = myConfig.gettokenValidityInMilliseconds()
     }

 public String createToken(Authentication authentication) {
        ....

        Date validity = new Date(now + this.tokenValidityInMilliseconds);

       ...
    }
```

with your ConfigRepository which is something like this

```
@Repository
public interface ConfigRepository extends CrudRepository<Config, String> {

}
```

hope it can help you